# React-Native Android Release build error: unknown option `--configuration'

Tags: react-native

So this isn't my first react native app but this is the first time i'm getting this error. I get the usual error when running:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Thats ok because I know it doesn't work. However, this one always use to work:

```
react-native run-android --configuration=release
```

But it is just stating: `error: unknown option`--configuration'`

I've had that issue before. I've done everything on the generate a signed APK web page. I can get a non-release but not the release. I even have the APK from: `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: i also have this issue and has been after upgrade to react-native 0.41, it works fine in 0.40. So i recommend to use the specific version of react native or if upgraded today rollback. I will keep you posted if i get any other solution.

Comment: @Kanekotic Thanks, you might want to create an issue on GitHub so we can discus this with other React people.

Answer (score 25):

Have you recently upgraded your React Native version?

Because the following only works on version 0.39.x

`react-native run-android --configuration=release`

Else, just use this

`react-native run-android --variant=release`

Comment: The one you are recommending has always failed me for multiple versions, it fails on installing appDebug at 97%. Saying that 'installReleaseDebug' not found in root project'.

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: version 0.41, everything up to date

Comment: I tested with 0.41 and was able to run `react-native run-android --variant=release` without any issue. What error did you see?

Comment: Can you try run `react-native run-android --variant=release` instead since your React Native version is 0.41.

Comment: That throws an error that is in my question. That command has never worked for me over previous versions.

Comment: If you are referring to the 'installReleaseDebug' not found error, yes that happens only in version 0.39.x when you run `--variant=release`. Since you said you are running version 0.41, do you still get that error when you run `--variant=release`?

Answer (score 5):

The `variant` flag was replaced by the `mode` flag for React Native 0.71 and updated in the docs in [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/commit/b3f5330e1836e1639c9f4e44ee86cff2f28e7a41). The [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) has been updated to use the following commands:

Building ([docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-aab)):

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

Testing the release build ([docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#testing-the-release-build-of-your-app)):

```
npm run android -- --mode="release"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the version-specific updates in commands.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:
`react-native run-android --mode=stagingdebug`

Answer (score -1):

In React Native 0.71, the variant flag was replaced with the mode flag. This change was made to simplify the configuration and improve clarity. The documentation has been updated to reflect this change, and you should now use the mode flag in your commands.

For example, if you previously used the variant flag like this:
react-native run-android --variant=release
react-native run-android --mode=release

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).